# auto add wmode=“opaque” first to embed with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, embed

I'm using the following script to add wmode="opaque" to embed elements:

```
jQuery("iframe[src], embed[src]").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).prop("src", jQuery(this).prop("src") + "?wmode=opaque");
});
```

it works fine, but adds the wmode at the last of the embed src like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/example?fs=1&feature=oembed?wmode=opaque
```

And that doesn't make it work. I want it to be more accurate so it adds wmode as the first attribute after the embed link so no matter how I past the embed url for example :

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/example?fs=1&feature=oembed
```

the script will make it like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/example?wmode=opaque?fs=1&feature=oembed
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should compensate for both thins, because

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/example?wmode=opaque?fs=1&feature=oembed
```

is also wrong, only the first param should have a `?`

So, you could try:

```
jQuery("iframe[src], embed[src]").each(function () {
    var url = jQuery(this).prop("src");
    if(url.search(/\?/) === -1) {
            jQuery(this).prop("src", url + "?wmode=opaque");
    } else {
            jQuery(this).prop("src", url + "&wmode=opaque");
    }
});
```

Just if you like your code to be smaller, you can replace the if statement by:

```
 jQuery(this).prop("src", url + ((url.search(/\?/) === -1) ? url + "?wmode=opaque" : "&wmode=opaque"));
```

Also I recommend you take a look at [Query string parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (in the link I left here, or by searching on google)

**EDIT**

I don't understand why you need it to be at the beginning, and I'm pretty sure that you just don't understand how query parameters work.
But, here is the code:

```
jQuery("iframe[src], embed[src]").each(function () {
    var url = jQuery(this).prop("src");
        if(url.search(/\?/) === -1) {
            jQuery(this).prop("src", url + "?wmode=opaque");
        } else {
            var splittedUrl = url.split("?");
            jQuery(this).prop("src", splittedUrl[0] + "?wmodeopaque&" + splittedUrl[1]);
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the code, i tried google but got nothing till now, can we make the code search for the "?" and add "wmode=opaque&" after it?